# .htaccess redirect to external url but with mod_rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

*I have two webspaces and one domain. In one of the webspaces, I have approximately 5 TB of audio files and images, while the other webspace is reserved for scripts.*

**Here's the problem I'm facing**:

Let's say my webspaces' URLs are 'domain1.tld' and 'domain2.tld'.

All my files and other assets are located on 'domain2.tld'.
I've only uploaded the PHP files to 'domain1.tld'.

The issue arises when I want to access a video, for example, located at 'domain2.tld/files/video01.mp4,' but the link mistakenly shows 'domain1.tld/files/video01.mp4.' How can I configure it so that if the file doesn't exist on 'domain1.tld,' it automatically redirects to 'domain2.tld'?

I found a similar question here, and the provided solution looks like this:

```
     Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
    # Turn mod_rewrite on
     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteBase /
    
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mydomain\.com$ [NC]
     RewriteRule ^subdirectory/?$ http://newurl.com [L,R=301,NC]
```

However, this solution has one problem:

If I go to http://domain1.tld/%FILE% and the file doesn't exist, it should redirect to http://domain2.tld/%FILE%.
Is it possible to achieve this using mod_rewrite?

In essence, I want it so that if 'domain1.tld/%FILE%' doesn't exist, it automatically accesses 'domain2.tld/%FILE%'.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ http://domain2.tld/$1 [L,R=302,NC]
```

It means: if file or directory or symlink not found here, do redirect to domain2.tld .

*(It's 302 because testing new rewrite rules with permanent redirect is dangerous )*